# Animating an INPUT of type RANGE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range

I have the following `input`:
`<input id="meepmeep" type="range" min="0" max="128" step="1" value="0" />`

And I'm doing a basic `setInterval()` call:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var newVal = $('#meepmeep').val() + 1;
    $('#meepmeep').val(newVal);
}, 500);
```

But the incremented `val() + 1` seems to be `val() + 50` any ideas?!

Fiddle for the lazy: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/SNYsa/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is parsed as a String.
Convert the datatype to a number to fix the issue:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var newVal = parseInt($('#meepmeep').val()) + 1;
    $('#meepmeep').val(newVal);
}, 500);
```

Comment: ahhhhhhhh! THAT'S what it is! Thank you for simply saying `STRING`!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic function that will slide to a given value on a range for a given jQuery element.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
   slideToValue(75, $("#slider"));
});

function slideToValue(num, $input) {
 const interval = function() {
   const cur = $input.val();
   
    if (cur < num) {
     console.log(`Value is ${cur}. Incrementing!`);
     $input.val(parseInt(cur) + 1);
    } else if (cur > num) {
     console.log(`Value is ${cur}. Decrementing!`);
     $input.val(parseInt(cur) - 1);
    } else {
     console.log(`Arrived at ${num}!`);
     clearInterval(slowly);
    }
  }
 const slowly = setInterval(interval, 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Set to 75</button>
<input type="range" id="slider">
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `.val()` returns a string, you should convert the string to a number before addition:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#meepmeep').val(function(i, str) { return ++str; });
}, 500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SNYsa/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var newVal = parseInt($('#meepmeep').val()) + 1.0;
    $('#meepmeep').val(newVal);
}, 500);
```

works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var newVal = $('#meepmeep').val() + 1;
```

**Result**

```
Run 
1st time value = 1
2nd time  = 11
3rd time = 111
4th time = 1111
```

Because you are adding to `string` not converting it to `integer value`

**Correct Code** [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SNYsa/2/)

```
setInterval(function() {
    var newVal = $('#meepmeep').val(function(i, val) {
       return +val + 1;
    });
}, 500);
```

or [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SNYsa/3/)

```
setInterval(function() {
    var newVal = parseInt($('#meepmeep').val()) + 1;
    $('#meepmeep').val(newVal);
}, 500);
```

Read [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)